# GCP MySQL Cloud SQL database does not properly export multibyte UTF-8 characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

When I create a backup of my MySQL Cloud SQL database, it does not export correctly the UTF-8 multibyte characters that it contains.

I feel this is a bug. But it could be that I am missing something. I hope somebody can help me out!

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Cloud SQL MySQL database. Using version 5.7. Be sure to set the flag `character_set_server` to `utf8mb4`.
2. Create a new database with `character_set` to `utf8mb4` and `collation` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
3. Populate the database:

   ```
   SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
   CREATE TABLE `slug` (
    `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   INSERT INTO demo.slug VALUES ('');
   ```
4. I validated that I can get those values back properly using the following:

   ```
   SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
   SELECT * FROM demo.slug;
   ```
5. Use the build-in export mechanism the Console provides.

   [image]
6. When you download the resulting SQL file, the relevant `INSERT` statement will look as follows. And contain question marks, instead of valid UTF-8 characters.

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO `slug` VALUES ('???');
   ```

   Note that I also get that exact value when I omit the `SET NAMES` part in step 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing it through the Console as you did, and I get to the same issue.
The workaround that worked for me is this one:

**1)** Whitelist you GCP project's public IP in

> STORAGE > SQL > your instance > CONNECTIONS > Connectivity > +Add
>   network

By running this command you can get the public IP `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

**2)** Create a .sql file by running this command: `mysqldump --databases [YOUR_DB_NAME] -h [YOUR_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP] -u [YOUR_USER] -p  --default-character-set=utf8mb4 > [FILE_NAME].sql`

**3)** Move the file into a bucket by running this command: `gsutil mv [FILE_NAME].sql gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/`

**4)** Then you import the file via Console, selecting the database you want.

I have tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Yeah I figured that would work. Thanks for that write-up.

So it really _does_ seem like a bug. It makes me wonder whether the *automatic* backups that are taken are actually valid. Or if emoji's are already scrambled there.

Comment: I got a reply from Google: _Engineering is aware of this.
No ETA on a change, however._

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ignore the below -- The success may have bee because the bytes making up the characters I tested were also valid latin-1 characters...

> It seems that this only affects 4-byte UTF-8 encoded characters (which
>   includes all the emoticons, etc.)
>
> Trying with a 3-byte character such as Cyrillic Zemlya (Ꙁ utf8=ea9980)
>   or a 2-byte character such as Greek Epsilon (Ɛ utf-8=ceb5) succeeds.
>
> Note that Cloud SQL backups do not use exports, so they are not
>   affected.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from Google: Engineering is aware of this. No ETA on a change, however. So there is no way to fix this. In the meantime the only way to make a valid backup is using iker's instructions.